# get the ContentResult from alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I want to get the get the **ContentResult**  from document which is in alfresco :

using this code

```
   ContentResult contentResult = AlfrescoClientWS.getContentsById(docid,"HTTP://192.168.8.100:9080/alfresco/api",
                    GedListener.credentialUser, GedListener.credentialPwd);
```

I work in jboss 7.1  and I use this jar :

**alfresco-web-service-client-4.0.d.jar,axis-1.4.jar,axis-saaj-1.2.jar,wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar,wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar,xmlsec-1.4.1.jar**

but when I test I have this error:

```
17:07:40,546 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myProject].[FileUploadServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet FileUploadServlet a généré une exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.staticInit(WSSConfig.java:244) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.<init>(WSSConfig.java:256) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:265) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:89) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:170) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentServiceSoapBindingStub.read(ContentServiceSoapBindingStub.java:467) [alfresco-web-service-client-4.0.d.jar:]
    at com.dq.urbanplanning.web.ged.AlfrescoClientWS.getContentsById(AlfrescoClientWS.java:162) [classes:]
............
.........
```

I have this class java :AlfrescoClientWS.java

```
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.Content;
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentFault;
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.QueryResult;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.UpdateResult;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CML;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLAddAspect;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLCreate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ContentFormat;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.NamedValue;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ParentReference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Predicate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Query;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Reference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ResultSet;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ResultSetRow;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Store;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Constants;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.ContentUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Utils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;


public class AlfrescoClientWS {

public static ContentResult getContentsById(String contentId, String cmurl, String userName, String pwd)
        throws Exception {
        ContentResult contentResult = new ContentResult();

        // Start the session
        WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress(cmurl);
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(userName, pwd);

        try {
            Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");
            ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

            Reference contentReference = new Reference(storeRef, contentId, null);
            Content[] readResult = null;

            try {
                readResult = contentService.read(new Predicate(new Reference[] { contentReference }, storeRef, null), Constants.PROP_CONTENT);
            } catch (ContentFault e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ((readResult != null) && (readResult[0] != null)) {
                Content content = readResult[0];
                ContentFormat cnf = content.getFormat();
                Reference ref = content.getNode();

                String[] splitedUrl = content.getUrl().split("/");
                String name = splitedUrl[splitedUrl.length - 1];

                InputStream is = ContentUtils.getContentAsInputStream(content);
                byte[] contentByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

                contentResult.setName(name);
                contentResult.setMimetype(cnf.getMimetype());
                contentResult.setId(ref.getUuid());
                contentResult.setUrl(content.getUrl());
                contentResult.setPath(ref.getPath());
                contentResult.setContentByte(contentByte);
                System.out.println(" document has been retrieved");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            // End the session
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();

            // System.exit(0);
        }

        return contentResult;
    }

}
```

the error is related to this line :

```
  readResult = contentService.read(new Predicate(new Reference[] { contentReference }, storeRef, null), Constants.PROP_CONTENT);
```

I test my code using Main class  with this code :

```
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.Content;
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentFault;
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.QueryResult;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.UpdateResult;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CML;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLAddAspect;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLCreate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ContentFormat;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.NamedValue;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ParentReference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Predicate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Query;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Reference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ResultSet;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ResultSetRow;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Store;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Constants;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.ContentUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Utils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;


public class AlfrescoClientWS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {


            ContentResult contentResult =AlfrescoClientWS.getContentsById("85e686c6-aecd-4747-9f2e-56d8c58a3e08",
                   "HTTP://192.168.0.100:9080/alfresco/api", "admin", "12345");

            System.out.println("-- contentResult:" + contentResult.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 public static ContentResult getContentsById(String contentId, String cmurl, String userName, String pwd)
        throws Exception {
        ContentResult contentResult = new ContentResult();

        // Start the session
        WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress(cmurl);
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(userName, pwd);

        try {
            Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");
            ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

            Reference contentReference = new Reference(storeRef, contentId, null);
            Content[] readResult = null;

            try {
                readResult = contentService.read(new Predicate(new Reference[] { contentReference }, storeRef, null), Constants.PROP_CONTENT);
            } catch (ContentFault e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ((readResult != null) && (readResult[0] != null)) {
                Content content = readResult[0];
                ContentFormat cnf = content.getFormat();
                Reference ref = content.getNode();

                String[] splitedUrl = content.getUrl().split("/");
                String name = splitedUrl[splitedUrl.length - 1];

                InputStream is = ContentUtils.getContentAsInputStream(content);
                byte[] contentByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

                contentResult.setName(name);
                contentResult.setMimetype(cnf.getMimetype());
                contentResult.setId(ref.getUuid());
                contentResult.setUrl(content.getUrl());
                contentResult.setPath(ref.getPath());
                contentResult.setContentByte(contentByte);
                System.out.println(" document has been retrieved");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            // End the session
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();

            // System.exit(0);
        }

        return contentResult;
    }

}
```

but when I test my code using jboss I have problem

Comment: Why are you using the old Alfresco WebServices client, instead of CMIS? CMIS can work with WS* if you want it to (though it's slower...)

Comment: can I work with alfresco-web-service-client-4.0.d.jar but just modify the other version of other jar

Comment: Are you sure that: Reference contentReference = new Reference(storeRef, contentId, null); this isn't empty/null or not a real reference? Have you debugged through it?

Comment: I can test my code using Main class , but when I want to test the same code using jboss 7.1 I have the previous error, I have updated my code